# SSL not working only on mobile websites

Tags: ios, apache, ssl, mobile, https

I had SSL certificate from StarCom for a year, after I reissued new certificate and replaces files on my apache2 server with ubuntu. Since than, I can't access my website on mobiles. Unfortunately, iOS doesn't show any errors, just blank page.

I checked all SSL checkers and they all give me A+. Here's part of my config:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/domain/new/domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/domain/new/private.key
# SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/domain/new/1_root_bundle.crt
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/domain/new/cer.crt
```

I spent whole night to find solution, but nothing. All certificates are valid, including CA. I tried to enable Chain, but no results anyway.

By debugging the iOS device using a Mac's Safari, I got this error:

Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “your.site.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startcom` is accepted on iOS, so the problem is in your server.

Probably you have misconfigured the certification chain. Configure `SSLCertificateChainFile` ensuring `1_root_bundle.crt` has all the certificate chain from the leaf (your cert) to the root (not included). In the case of starcom i think they have 1 intermediate, so the chain will have two certificates

The chain is just a concatenation of PEM-encoded certificates. If you open `1_root_bundle.crt` you will see a text like `----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----` and `----- END CERTIFICATE -----`

i am not sure if apache require the full chain in `SSLCertificateChainFile` attribute or only the intermediates. If you are using apache 2.4.8, you can include all certs in `domain.crt`and forget this attribute. See [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile)

Remove also  `SSLCACertificateFile`